# How stop a looping in the fourty loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm pulling data from my database, and sending for my views through my controllers. The date is coming, and I'm rendering this data in the HTML with a looping.

The problem is that I want to show only 4 items, not all. How can I solve this?

For example:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++ { %>
 <p> <%= data[i].name %>
 <p> <%= data[i].age %>
<% } %>
```

I want only render 4 times. How achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
<% for(var i = 0,max = (data.length > 4 ? 4 : data.length); i < max; i++ { %>
 <p> <%= data[i].name %>
 <p> <%= data[i].age %>
<% } %>
```

What this does is iterate the loop either 4 times or the length of data (whichever is shorter). If you don't have that conditional, you might get into an index out of bounds (if data.length is 2, for example).

**Coding note**: its good practice to declare max at the beginning of the for-loop. Its more readable and, for performance sakes, the lookup of the length attribute of data only happens once (instead of each iteration).

---

**Update based on comments**

To add other conditionals (such as if the pageName = 'home')

```
<% for(var i = 0,max = ( (data.length > 4 && pageName === 'home') ? 4 : data.length); i < max; i++ { %>
 <p> <%= data[i].name %>
 <p> <%= data[i].age %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: a question: can i apply this max only if my url matches with http://something.com/ ?? I am using the same code in two places, index, and a particular page for google remarketing, the index should show only 4 times, and the /events should show all. This is possible??

Comment: I'm not 100% sure of your question, but... if try to reuse the max I included, it will return 4 or the max of the data array (whichever is shorted), regardless of the page.

Comment: i know that.. but like I said, I would like to apply the max on one page, the home, but the code is serving to two pages - home and events. Is there any way to identify the page using EJS and apply the max only if the page is = home?

Comment: If you have a variable defining the what page you are on, then yes... it would look something like: 

`max = ( (data.length > 4 && pageName === 'home') ? 4 : data.length)`

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
<% for(var i = 0; i < data.length && i<4; i++ { %>
 <p> <%= data[i].name %>
 <p> <%= data[i].age %>
<% } %>
```

Comment: a question: can i apply this only if my url matches with http://something.com/ ?? I am using the same code in two places, index, and a particular page for google remarketing, the index should show only 4 times, and the /events should show all. This is possible??